# Filesystem/RAID configuration to stripe/mirror three hard drives

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, raid, btrfs, zfs

I have 3 HDDs in my workstation:

- 1.5 TB (drive "A")
- 2TB (drive "B")
- 4TB (drive "C")

I am doing a fresh install of 16.04.  I would like to find a filesystem/RAID configuration that allows me to have the following setup:

> - 500GB on C for boot, home, etc. (possibly multiple partitions)
> - 3.5 TB on C for storage partition
> - A and B striped so they appear as one partition / drive
> - The 3.5TB storage partition on C to be mirrored on the single striped A/B partition/drive

I've read a little about ZFS and btrfs and am wondering whether, for example, it's possible to setup a ZFS pool that behaves the way I'm looking for.  The 500GB could be ext4 etc. but ZFS and btrfs both have nice features that, from what I've read, would benefit a data storage partition.  I'm inclined to find a solution using ZFS due to the support now in 16.04, but open to any solutions that meet my requirements.

I've read about RAID10 and RAID01 but those look like they need 4 HDD.  But perhaps there is a RAID configuration that does what I want, using some combination of ext4/LVM/ZFS/btrfs.

I would greatly appreciate any advice on what is (a) possible and (b) recommended for this scenario!

Comment: What is your own attempt?

Answer (score 1):

Can accomplish what you want, drive A and drive B as appearing as 1 drive with btrfs.

Command to use full capacity of multiple drives with different sizes (metadata mirrored, data not mirrored and not striped):

mkfs.btrfs -d single /dev/sda /dev/sdb

There will be no redundancy with this setup, so if 1 drive goes out all the data will be lost.

Check out the btrfs wiki page on multi-drive setups.
https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Using_Btrfs_with_Multiple_Devices

Comment: Once A and B appear as one drive, is there another btrfs command to mirror (data) between C and the merged AB?  Like you hinted at, if A or B fails, I would want to be able to restore from C (or vice versa).

Answer (score 0):

The hard plans you have can not exactly be achieved with btrfs, simply because you can not configure it that way. Btrfs can be told to use a specific raid level but it will decide by itself on which drive it will put the data and where to put the mirrorored data.

With an MD array you can do that. First create a striped array with drive A and B and then create a mirrored array with the stripe + DriveC-data-partition. But that would be too complicated for me. Configuring/Re-configuring this will be a real pain matching exact sizes of the partitions and so on...

However if you add all 3 data partitions into one btrfs file system you should end up with more or less what you intend.

mkfs.btrfs -d raid1 /dev/sda1 /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdcx

ZFS: I do not know...